# Mockito verify no _default_ interaction

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class with methods that return different forms of the same thing. I only need to know one of them is called and I don't want to be overly restrictive about which.

I tried setting the default answer (second argument to `mock()`) to throw an exception, but the exception was thrown even when I was setting up the stub (i.e. in the `when(...)` call)! The documentation does not recommend using this either.

So is there a propery way to verify/allow only the methods with explicit stubs to be called?

Comment: Have you tied the alternative syntax `doReturn(...).when(mock).method()` ?

Comment: I have considered that, but it feels so ugly... The documentation also says the default answer is meant to be used for legacy purpose.

Comment: It's ugly but it's the only way. The documentation says it's mostly useful for legacy systems, but that doesn't mean it's the only usage. However what would concerns me here is the like of determinim in a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's a [`ignoreStubs()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/Mockito.html#25) added in 1.9 that does exactly this. Usage:

```
verifyNoMoreInteractions(ignoreStubs(mock, mockTwo));
```